# Dynamic combo chart that changes via month selector

Tags: excel

I'm trying to build a dashboard that can update detailed information based on the "Month Selector." I have a named range with the formula:

```
=OFFSET('Labor Data'!$B$1,MATCH(MATCH(Dashboard!$T$3,Dashboard!$C$3:$N$3,0)-1,'Labor Data'!$A:$A),0,MAX(IF('Labor Data'!$A:$A=MATCH(Dashboard!$T$3,Dashboard!$C$3:$N$3,0),ROW('Labor Data'!$A:$A)))-MATCH(MATCH(Dashboard!$T$3,Dashboard!$C$3:$N$3,0),'Labor Data'!$A:$A,0)+1,5)
```

I know it works. It properly highlights the range I would expect in the data worksheet. But when I plug the name of the range into the Chart Data Range field, the Horizontal Axis Labels resolve and doesn't change when I change the month. Is there any way to keep the Horizontal axis dynamic?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the named range and wrote the solution into VBA that triggers when the dropdown box's value is changed.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal monthSel As Range)

```
Set dash = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set labor = Worksheets("Labor Data")

setMonth = dash.Range("T3").Value

If Not Intersect(monthSel, Range("T3")) Is Nothing Then

    monthNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(setMonth, dash.Range("C3:N3"), 0)
    
    Set dynRangeTop = labor.Range("A:A").Find(monthNum, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set dynRangeBot = labor.Range("A:A").Find(monthNum, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    Set chartRng = labor.Range("C" & dynRangeTop.Row & ":" & "G" & dynRangeBot.Row)
    
    dash.ChartObjects("MonthSum").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=chartRng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
End If

End Sub
```